# Get the top keyword in an array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
var words = { 'love': 4; 'peace': 10; 'war':3; 'family':13; 'dog':19, 'life':7 };
```

What is the fastest way to get the top 2 keywords (family and dog in this case) ?

Comment: Show us what you have tried yet so far.

Comment: not a valid object as well.

Comment: and it is not true, that dogs are more important than love!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the keys and sort them with their values descending and take the first 2 elements.

```js
var words = { 'love': 4, 'peace': 10, 'war': 3, 'family': 13, 'dog': 19, 'life': 7 },
    top2 = Object.keys(words).sort(function (a, b) {
        return words[b] - words[a];
    }).slice(0, 2);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(top2, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```